# Cómo usar el evento onkeypress fuera del HTMl

Tags: javascript, html

mi problema es el siguiente: ¿Cómo poder usar el evento fuera de mi htm, es decir: Que mi evento 'onkeypress' no este dentro de la etiqueta html sino en javascript?  Quiero separar el código. Aclaro que este código me funciona.

```js
function permite(elEvento,permitidos) {
        switch(permitidos) {
                case 'num':
                var evento = elEvento || window.event;
                var codigoCaracter = evento.charCode || evento.keyCode;
                var caracter = String.fromCharCode(codigoCaracter);

                
                if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(caracter)){
                    permitidos=false;
                }
                return permitidos;
                break;  
        }
                
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label  class="font-weight-bold" for="matricula_2">Matricula *</label >
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Matricula: 1629????" onkeypress="return permite(event,'num')" id="matricula_1" maxlength="10" required>
  
</div>
```

sadsads

Answer (score 1):

Puedes checarlo aquí en creo que es la opción que buscas  [Jquery keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: No me funciona no se porque, ya inclui la libreria, me marca error en la consola del navegador  y solo desaparece ese error si esta dentro de una función                                      
    $( "#matricula_1" ).keypress(function( event ) {
       
    });

Answer (score 1):

Ya me salio, dejo el código por si alguien lo quiere:

```
document.getElementById("demo").onkeypress = function() {           
    return permite("event",'num')
};    
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
    placeholder="Matricula: 1629????" id="demo" maxlength="10" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `addEventListener`, la idea es agregar un evento en este caso el evento es 'keypress'

```js
function permite(elEvento, permitidos) {

  console.log('accion escuchada');
  

}

document.addEventListener('keypress', permite, false);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="font-weight-bold" for="matricula_2">Matricula *</label >
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Matricula: 1629????"  id="matricula_1" maxlength="10" required>
  
</div>
```